# How to open files, web browsers, and URLs in Python, not in IDLE.

Tags: python, file, browser

I know you can open files, browsers, and URLs in the Python GUI. However, I don't know how to apply this to programs. For example, none of the below work. (The below are snippets from my growing chat bot program):

```
def browser():
    print('OPENING FIREFOX...')
    handle = webbroswer.get() # webbrowser is imported at the top of the file
    handle.open('http://youtube.com')
    handle.open_new_tab('http://google.com')
```

and

```
def file():
    file = str(input('ENTER THE FILE\'S NAME AND EXTENSION:'))
    action = open(file, 'r')
    actionTwo = action.read()
    print (actionTwo)
```

These errors occur, in respect to the above order, but in individual runs:

```
OPENING FIREFOX...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 202, in <module>
    askForQuestions()
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 64, in askForQuestions
    browser()
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 38, in browser
    handle = webbroswer.get()
NameError: global name 'webbroswer' is not defined
>>> 

ENTER THE FILE'S NAME AND EXTENSION:file.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 202, in <module>
    askForQuestions()
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 66, in askForQuestions
    file()
  File "C:/Users/RCOMP/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/AI/COMPUTRON_01.py", line 51, in file
    action = open(file, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
>>>
```

Am I handling this wrong, or can I just not use open() and webbrowser in a program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the errors and try to understand them - they are very helpful in this case - as they often are:

The first one says `NameError: global name 'webbroswer' is not defined`.
You can see here that `webbrowser` is spelled wrong in the code. It also tells you the line it finds the error (line 38)

The second one `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'` tells you that you're trying to open a file that doesn't exist. This does not work because you specified

```
    action = open(file, 'r')
```

which means that you're trying to read a file. Python does not allow reading from a file that does not exist.

Comment: +1 for the suggesting the OP should read and understand the errors.

Comment: Yeah, shame; I should have caught the 'broswer'. But alas, my poor vision and attentiveness have failed me yet again. Regarding 'file': since the variable 'file' equals my input  (file.txt), and indeed I have a file named 'file.txt' which does exist, it should work. Moreover, I agree, understanding errors is a key part of debugging. I'll get to it. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: If you have a file named 'file.txt' it's probably either a permissions problem or a path problem. You could try running Python as administrator to check for permission problems. As for path problems: How are you invoking your script? If you use for example 'python AI/COMPUTRON_01.py' then 'file.txt' should be in the 'Python Files' folder.